# MYSQL Database error: "pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your-"

Tags: python, mysql, navicat

Original Title: *pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Condition, KitLens, PurchasePrice) VALUES ('Nikon', 'HEWWO', '2020-06-11', 'OHH ' at line 1")*

I keep getting this error upon running MYSQL database for cameras. Upon trying to create a new camera, I come up with the error:

> *pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'Condition, KitLens, PurchasePrice)
>   VALUES ('Nikon', 'HEWWO', '2020-06-11', 'OHH ' at line 1")*

I have tried to troubleshoot and fix MYSQL table in Navicat, in my app.py file, and html file but to no avail. I'm thinking it maybe because of some certain whitespace in the code? 
Here is my code snippet for creating a new camera which I am sure is only necessary to share here as it is part of the problem:

```
    @app.route("/new_camera", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
    def newcamera():
        connection=create_connection()
        if request.method =="POST":
            get = request.form
            Company = get["Company"]
            Model = get["Model"]
            PurchaseDate = get["PurchaseDate"]
            Condition = get["Condition"]
            KitLens = get["KitLens"]
            PurchasePrice = get["PurchasePrice"]

            #photo=
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Create a new record
              sql = "INSERT INTO `tblcameras` (Company, Model, PurchaseDate, Condition, KitLens, PurchasePrice) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
              val=(Company, Model, PurchaseDate, Condition, KitLens, PurchasePrice)
              cursor.execute(sql, val)
              #save values in dbase
              connection.commit()
              cursor.close()
              return redirect("/cameras")
        return redirect(url_for('cameras?do=new', title="Add New camera"))
        #return render_template("cameras.html",title="Adding New camera")
```

**and my adding new camera html code:**

```
   {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}

    {% if (request.args.get('do')=='new' )%}
<br />
<h2>New camera</h2>
<form method="post" action="/new_camera" class="was-validated">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Company">Company:</label>
         <select id="Company" name="Company" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="Canon">Canon</option>
            <option value="Nikon">Nikon</option>
         </select>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Model">Model:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Model" placeholder="Enter Model" name="Model" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PurchaseDate">Purchase Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="PurchaseDate" placeholder="Purchase Date" name="PurchaseDate" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Condition">Condition:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Condition" placeholder="Enter Condition" name="Condition" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Kit Lens">Kit Lens</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="KitLens" placeholder="Enter Kit Lens (mm) or Standard" name="KitLens" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Purchase Price">Purchase Price</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" step="any" class="form-control" id="PurchasePrice" placeholder="Enter Purchase Price ($)" name="PurchasePrice" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<hr />
{% endif %}

<br />

<h2>
    Existing cameras
</h2>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        {%for camera in cameras%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{camera.Company}} {{camera.Model}}</td>
            <td> 
            <a href="/camera?do=edit&id={{camera.cameraId}}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a> 
            <a href="/camera?do=details&id={{camera.cameraId}}" class="btn btn-success">Details</a> 
            <a href="/camera?do=delete&id={{camera.cameraId}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>

        {%endfor%}

    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is also a screenshot of the data I tried to fill in:

[Adding A New Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1qyQ.png)

I tried looking at the other suggested questions and errors similar to this but I could not find a solution within any of them for my context. If you need any more information please let me know, Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `tblcameras` (Company, Model, PurchaseDate,`Condition`, KitLens, PurchasePrice) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

use backticks liek you did for your table